# Gulp wont restart in any of my projects

Tags: sass, gulp

I've started using gulp for a few projects, mainly to watch my sass files.

Recently every time I go back to a project, I browse to it in terminal type 'gulp watch' and all that happens is gulp starts, runs 'watch' and finishes the task and my files aren't actually being watched.

I've had this working in numerous projects but all of a sudden I can't 'restart' work on anything as what I explained above happens.

Am i doing something obviously wrong?

Edit: here is some more info:

npm: 1.4.21

Gulp file:

```
    var gulp = require('gulp'),
        sass = require('gulp-sass'),
        autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');


// SASS build
gulp.task('sass', function () {
    gulp.src('./sass/styles.sass')
            .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
            .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});


// Watch files
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.sass', ['sass']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch', 'sass', 'autoprefixer']);
```

Comment: You need to provide *way* more information if you want a hope of an answer. Show us a sample gulpfile, and preferably the versions of node / gulp / other dependencies. We don't have a clue what `gulp watch` does, since you define your own tasks with Gulp.

Comment: I have added more details now Oka.

Comment: No issues getting this [working](http://pastebin.com/71t3GMAR) on `node@0.12.2`, `npm@2.7.4`, `gulp@3.9.0`, `gulp-sass@2.0.1`. You have no errors? Does the terminal hang after running `gulp watch`, or kick you back to prompt? The `watch` task *should* run, and finish immediately - it's only creating a listener for the directories / files you've specified. The `sass` task should then be the one running every time you change a `.sass` file in `./sass/**/`, from which it compiles `./sass/styles.sass`. Are you importing partials correctly?